# Are there any rings with exactly one irreducible element up to units but no prime elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

By a ring I mean any model of the equational theory of commutative rings with a unit in the signature $(0, 1, -, +, *)$.

I have been trying off and on for the past few days to prove or come up with a counterexample to the claim that *in every ring with exactly one irreducible $p$ up to multiplication by units, $p$ is prime*. This is straightforwardly equivalent to the claim: *every ring with exactly one irreducible up to units has exactly one prime*.

**Are there any rings with exactly one irreducible up to units but no primes?**

---

What follows is my attempt so far to solve the problem. **Note that the proof attempt below is wrong and fails for $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, among other rings, as pointed out in the comments.**

So far, I have an explicit example of a ring with exactly one irreducible $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

I also have a proof that every finite ring with exactly one irreducible has exactly one prime.

Let's consider taking an arbitrary ring element $a$ and producing a factorization tree for $a$. A factorization tree is a binary tree that *ends* when *a* is a zero or a unit or irreducible, when *a* is not a zero, not a unit, and not irreducible, we must split $a$ into two non-units. For example, the following is a factorization tree in $\mathbb{Z}$.

```
     12
   /   \
  2     6
       / \
      -2 -3
```

I claim that if my underlying ring is finite, then all factorization trees are finite.

If I start off with zero, a unit, or an irreducible, then my factorization tree is a singleton tree.

Suppose my starting ring element is neither zero, nor a unit, nor irreducible. In that case, my tree is infinite if and only if I repeat an interior node of the factorization tree. However, if I repeat an interior node, that would imply that $1$ is a finite product of irreducibles, which does not hold.

So, all factorization trees are finite.

However, if I have exactly one irreducible, it follows that the leaves of my factorization tree are all identical up to multiplication by a unit.

Therefore, every element of my ring has the form $p^ku$ where $k$ is a natural number and $u$ is a unit.

Comment: I assume you work with commutative rings? But you do not restrict to integral domains?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes. By a ring I mean any model of the equational theory of commutative rings with 1. Sorry, I thought that was the default meaning of ring.

Comment: If you repeat an interior node, you get an equation $x=xy$ where $y$ is may be a product over several vertices of the tree. Then $x(y-1)=0$, which does not imply that $y=1$.

Comment: For a concrete example, look at $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ where $2$ is not a unit, not zero, and not irreducible because $2=2\cdot4$. Together with $4=2\cdot2$ this allows for an infinite tree on a finite ring.

Comment: I see. A unit is pretty standard (unfortunately still no universal standard, since it should https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0135), but commutativity is definitely not. I suggest that you add this requirement to the question.

Comment: When you have a domain with a factorization into irreducible elements (eg Noetherian domain or Noetherian local ring), then every nonzero element must be (up to a unit) a power of $p$, thus every nonzero ideal is a power of $p$, and therefore $(p)$ is maximal. This means counter-examples will be rather wild.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg  Your "definitely not" claim is too strong, e.g. one can argue that in some contexts it is more conveneient to use the defauilt assumption that rings are commutative e.g. see discussion in [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12937/242).