# Ways of insisting that factorization trees for ring elements in commutative rings make progress

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For commutative rings with unity, I'm interested in characterizing *factorization steps* when drawing a factorization tree that are guaranteed to make progress. I don't want to insist on termination, but some notion of *progress* would be nice and termination in finite rings would be nice.

Let a ring element $r$ be *strictly factorizable* (**not a standard term**) if and only if there exist ring elements $a$ and $b$ such that $r = ab$ and $(r) \subsetneq (a)$ and $(r) \subsetneq (b)$.

My question is threefold:

1. What is the standard way to talk about factorization trees in commutative rings, if one exists? What is the standard way to rule out ill-formed ones?
2. Where does the strict factorizability stopping criterion work besides obvious cases like finite or more generally Noetherian rings?
3. Is there a standard name for something like strict factorizability?

---

What follows is context:

In [a failed proof attempt in a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600797/are-there-any-rings-with-exactly-one-irreducible-element-up-to-units-but-no-prim), I tried describing a factorization rule where $0$, units, and irreducibles were excluded from splitting but nothing else.

In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600797/are-there-any-rings-with-exactly-one-irreducible-element-up-to-units-but-no-prim#comment9691891_4600797), a user helpfully points out that $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ contains the number $2$ which factorizes as $2*4$ and isn't irreducible. So my original stopping rule doesn't work and mishandles zero divisors.

```
   2
  / \
 4   2
    / \
   4  ...
```

My current idea for a "stopping rule" for numbers in a factorization tree is that we only allow strict factorizations ... i.e. the ideals in both the left and right branches must get strictly larger.

For finite rings, this has to work. All the ideals are finite and I only permit factorization when both branches grow, so the tree cannot be taller than the cardinality of the ring.

We do get some weird stuff, like $0$ is strictly factorizable as $2*3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, but not strictly factorizable in $\mathbb{Z}$.